# Spring batch partitioning master can read database and pass data to workers?

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring batch and trying to design a new application which has to read 20 million records from database and process it.

I don’t think we can do this with one single JOB and Step(in sequential with one thread).

I was thinking we can do this in Partitioning where step is divided into master and multiple workers (each worker is a thread which does its own process can run parallel).

We have to read a table(existing table) which has 20 million records and process them but in this table we do not have any auto generated sequence number and it have primary key like employer number with 10 digits.

I checked few sample codes for Partitioning where we can pass the range to each worker and worker process given range like worker1 from 1 to 100 and worker2 101 to 200…but in my case which is not going work because we don’t have sequence number to pass as range to each worker.

In Partitioning can master read the data from database (like 1000 records) and pass it to each worker in place for sending range ? .

Or for the above scenario do you suggest any other better approach.

Comment: Can you give an example of a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle any query that returns result rows in a deterministic order is amenable to partitioning as in the examples you mentioned by means of `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` options. The `ORDER BY` may considerably increase the query execution time, although if you order by the table's primary key then this effect should be less noticeable as the table's index will already be ordered. So I would give this approach a try first, as it is the most elegant IMHO. 
Note however that you might run into other problems processing a huge result set straight from a `JdbcCursorItemReader`, because some RDBMSs (like MySQL) won't be happy with the rate at which you'd be fetching rows interlocked with processing. So depending on the complexity of your processing I would recommend validating the design in that regard early on. 
Unfortunately it is not possible to retrieve a partition's entire set of table rows and pass it as a parameter to the worker step as you suggested, because the parameter must not serialize to more than a kilobyte (or something in that order of magnitude). 
An alternative would be to retrieve each partition's data and store it somewhere (in a map entry in memory if size allows, or in a file) and pass the reference to that resource in a parameter to the worker step which then reads and processes it.